# Android GIS - Reverse Geocode using Shapefile (.shp)

Tags: android, mysql, gis, reverse-geocoding, shapefile

I want to develop an Android application. I'm still a newbie here.

All I want is to develop my app just like a GIS that can implement reverse geocode.
So I can put a coordinates (Long & Lat) and then gave us a city name for example as a feedback.

But I don't want to implement Reverse Geocode using Geocoder from Google, all I want is what coordinates that I entered is to be checked from shapefile (.shp) on the database, then gave a city name as a feedback. And I want to use MySQL as a database for my shapefile (shp). Is it possible, and what should I do to make it happens? Could you gave a tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23561/sql-query-to-reverse-geocoding-in-postgis
I asked on the gis forum, and I'd already try this.